# SSH Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: ssh, permission-denied

Try to build a k8s test bed cluster with vagrant box, during ssh config phase ssh-copy-id always timeout.

Try to run:

```
ssh -v vagrant@192.168.0.21
```

The message show an error message：

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

Guess the error is related to ssh server, then try to compare the config with another machine that can login with ssh correct.

Finally find that there have a config item `PasswordAuthentication` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, the value in vagrant box is `no`, but the value in another machine is `yes`

Try to update the value to `yes` and restart the box, the ssh login worked as expected.